# Composer 'create-project' command not downloading laravel

Tags: laravel, windows-10, composer-php

Already installed composer to 'C:/xampp/htdocs/crud' with cmd. However trying to install laravel via the 'composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog' command does not download or install anything. The 'composer global require laravel/installer' command produces the same result.

PS: don't know if it wrecks anything but, I was having trouble running the composer command at first, kept saying there is no app to open '.phar' files. I found an answer here that asked me run .phar files with php.exe by default and thats what i did.

A picture to show what happens when I run the composer commands to install laravel...
[image: A picture to show what happens when I run the composer commands to install laravel...]

Comment: This looks like it ignores the arguments and options passed to composer, i.e. as if you just run `php composer`. This might be related to whatever you did to make composer run. Have you tried it with `php C:/xampp/htdocs/crud/composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`?

Comment: @dbrumann That worked for me. Downloads in progress now